# Problem Trimming tailing characters

Tags: bash, shell-script, string, tail, bioinformatics

I've got the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

SINGLE=`cut -c 7-21 Data.txt`

cd ../FASTA_SEC/

for i in ${SINGLE}; do
    if [ -r ../FASTA_SEC/${i}.fa ]; then
        HEAD=`sed -n 2p ../FASTA_SEC/${i}.fa | head -c 3`
        TAIL=`tail -c 4 ../FASTA_SEC/${i}.fa`
            if [ "${HEAD}" = "AAA" ]
            then
                    echo "Cut heading A's" $i
                elif [ "${TAIL}" = "AAA" ]
                then
                        echo "Cut tailing A's" $i
                    while [ `tail -c 2 ../FASTA_SEC/$i.fa` == "A" ]
                     do
                        TRITAIL=`cat ../FASTA_SEC/$i.fa`
                        echo ${TRITAIL/A/} > ../FASTA_SEC/$i.fa
                    done
            fi
    else 
        echo "does not exist" $i
    fi
done
```

It seems to work in all processed text files including the while loop. But there are a couple of text files where all A's are removed and some spaces are introduced instead of deleting only the tailing A's.

I'm quite surprised because it actually works but in some cases it produces a mess. Let me show you an example:

Input file which contains A tailing:

```
>B4-0K032_18670_015
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCNNNGNNNTAGATACAAGCGAGCGGC
GGACGGGTGAGTAACACGTGGGTAACCTGCCCAAGAGACTGGGATAACACCTGGAAACAG
[Cuted here for shortness]
GGNTGTCNTCNGCTNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNAAAAAAAA
```

Output messed up file:

```
>G4-0K047_18670_010 NNNNNNNNNNCCNCCTGTNNNTTTGCCCCCGGGGGCCTGTCTCTCGGTGTC GTGTCGCCTGGTGGTTCTTCGCGTTGCTTCGTTCCCTGCTCCC
[Cuted here for shortness]
CGTCCGCCNTCGTTCCTGNTGTCTCGGTGCNNGCCCGTNTNNNNNNNNNN NNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

I want only tailing A's to be cut but in some text files a mess occurs but in most of them it works smoothly. In some files where tailing A's are supposed to be trimmed I get this mess (even other characters might are deleted as well..).

I wonder wwy it does work in some cases but in some it does not..
Would there be a way to trim tailing A's?

Comment: Have you tried running the script under `set -xv` to see what the shell sees?

Comment: I'm sorry I dont know whats `set -xv`. how can I run it?  I tried to type `set -xv bash script.sh` but it does not work

Comment: No, insert the line before the 2nd line of your script.

Comment: If you just want to cut trailing `A`s from the ends of lines, why not use `sed 's/A*$//'`?

Comment: I've tryed your suggestion but it deletes all the tailing A's from each line. I would like to tail A's only in the last line

Comment: (@DopeGhoti) `sed '$s/A*$//'` does the change only on the last line. Modern `sed` has `-i` (inplace) which stores back to the same file, otherwise do something like `sed '$s/A*$//' file >temp && mv temp file` or since your files are apparently small `sed '$s/A*$//' file | sponge file`. To have sed do it only when there are at least 3 `'${/AAA$/s/A*$//}'`

Comment: Ill take a view of that sed suggestions im more familiar to sed. Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole script ends up depending of this two lines to remove trailing "A"'s:

```
tritail=$(cat ../FASTA_SEC/$i.fa)
echo ${tritail/A/} > ../FASTA_SEC/"$i".fa
```

Since you are already placing the whole file content in a variable, you do not need a loop to remove all trailing A's. You could just do:

```
tritail="$(cat ../FASTA_SEC/"$i".fa)"
shopt -s extglob
echo ${tritail#+(A)} > ../FASTA_SEC/"$i".fa
```

Or, if you dislike changing the extglob setting:

```
tritail="$(cat ../FASTA_SEC/"$i".fa)"
echo "${tritail%"${tritail##*[!A]}"}" > ../FASTA_SEC/"$i".fa
```

In fact, those two commands is all you need to remove trailing A's.

---

The second line works by selecting all the trailing A's. Or, as the command actually does it, by removing everything that is **not** an A ([!A]) at the leading part of the variable:

```
tail=${tritail##*[!A]}          # Select all the trailing A's
```

And then, the resulting string is removed from the trailing part of the variable:

```
result=${tritail%"$tail"}       # Remove the trailing A's
```

Both parameter expansions are join together into one single command:

```
result=${tritail%"${tritail##*[!A]}"}
```

And that is what is sent to the (modified) file:

```
echo "${tritail%"${tritail##*[!A]}"}" > ../FASTA_SEC/"$i".fa
```

To remove leading A's, switch all the selections:

```
echo "${tritail#"${tritail%%[!A]*}"}" > ../FASTA_SEC/"$i".fa
```

Comment: It works as desired! Could you explain briefly the second code line (I used unchanged extglob. Btw what if we would want to trim heading A's from second line?

Comment: @Neuls Expanded description and leading removal added.